# How to change the speed of a road segment after simulation starts?

Tags: veins, sumo

I want to change the speed of a road section after sometime from the simulation start. For an example, at time step = 50, the speed of a particular road segment should be set to 5 m/s though its original speed has been something else (e.g. 15 m/s) before the specified time step.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SUMO's TraCI interface](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI) supports both [changing the state of individual lanes](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_Lane_State) or [changing the state of entire edges](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Change_Edge_State). All you need to do is send the required command (0xc3 or 0xca) and the required variable (0x41 in both cases).